# PhpStorm - Mark multiple lines

Tags: linux, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.3

Is it possible to mark multiple lines in PhpStorm?

e.g.

```
LineA
LineB
LineC
```

lets say I try to mark **LineA** and **LineC** to copy paste them to another place, is this possible?

```
LineA
LineC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure .. but it requires a bit of "precision pointing" and using mouse (not sure if it's easily doable with keyboard only).

Basically -- the idea is to use [Multiple Carets functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/multicursor.html):

1. Place caret at the beginning of first line
2. Now <kbd>Alt + Click</kbd> on the beginning of the other line to create new caret there (shortcut depends on OS -- on Linux it might be different shortcut/combo as that shortcut may used by Desktop/Window manager for own stuff)
3. Now you have 2 carets on the beginning of `Line A` and `Line C`
4. Just use <kbd>Shift + End</kbd> to select text to the end of line -- it will be done in both lines.
5. Now just Copy + Paste it elsewhere (or whatever you wanted to do).
6. Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get rid of carets.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as I know the correct shortcut for linux.

Comment: @Black this is the wrong approach. The correct approach is to try it until you find the correct shortcut for Linux. It works with `Ctrl-Alt-Shit-click` for me.

Comment: @Black Well -- just check (and change if needed) what shortcut is associated with `Editor Actions | Add or Remove Caret` action in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`

Answer (score 3):

Use [multiple cursors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/multicursor.html). The keyboard shortcuts may vary (those described in the documentation do not work for me on Linux).

Explore clicking around the text while various combinations of the `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `Shift` keys are pressed. On macOS also try `Cmd`. One of them allows you to place multiple carets in the text (f.e. at the beginning of the lines you want to copy).

After you placed all the carets you need use `Shift` and the arrows to extend the selection. Use `Copy` and `Paste` as usual. Use `Escape` or click anywhere in the text to deselect and go back to the regular, single-caret, status.